# How safe is my soucecode in my APK?

Tags: android, security, apk, source-code-protection

I was wondering how safe my source code is in my APK? By this I mean. If i give my apk to someone, could he see my sourcecode or could he extract, unzip, decompile the APK? With or without extra programs?

Or is this not possible?

Comment: Why downvote? Isn't this a good question? ifnot what should I have typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a user can try to decompile and see the source code and its possible to decompile a apk. But, it will take time to decompile and understand this code. So, to prevent this you can use **Proguard** to prevent it from understanding the code.

Comment: Oke :D indeed this is what I need, and if you decompile the proguarded version what do you see? bytecode? or just encrypted code. an

Comment: Its encrypted code like it will convert the class names to random names like A,B,....Z which is very difficult to understand.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out

Comment: so if you decompile it will look like this -> http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-S4jYYohH6fw/Uooe7KDPImI/AAAAAAAAEpQ/1y31P2BSgvY/s1600/obfuscate02.png

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren WC :)

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren exactly.